# Gimp How can I prevent folder loading in Export Window?

Tags: gimp

Sequence of events:

1. Export As...
2. Export Image window opens, and begins loading the file's location folder.

This takes forever because the folder is huge.
Is there a way to tell gimp "do not load the folder's files"?
A plugin or preference?

v2.10.34

Comment: Huge folders are bad for all applications (this said, what is "huge", because the file dialog is still instantaneous for me on a directory with 2000+ files of various image types).  Couldn't find a way to disable file icons in the dialog (which is probably the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Export to elsewhere, maybe to a prepared empty folder. Have one as a spare for future quick needs. Move the file later.